# SVG logo not loading in Chrome or Opera

Tags: logo

I exported the logo into an svg file, using Illustrator and Photoshop. The logo displays on Firefox and Safari but not on Chrome and Opera. Any idea why?

Am I suppose to export it w some sort of settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was something wrong with the EPS file itself. I opened a PDF version of the logo in Illustrator, converted that to svg and it works now!